# get col headers of clf.feature_importances in python

Tags: python

I have implemented `DecisionTreeClassifier` and got feature importance list.
I tried adding col names to it but couldn't.

Can you help?

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100,
                               max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)*100)

print(clf.feature_importances_)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you load X_train as pandas DataFrame to add feature name with feature importance try below code:

```
for feature, importance in zip(X_train.columns, clf.feature_importances_):
    print(feature, importance)
```